# How to properly use the Excel DAY function

Tags: excel, data-analysis

What am I doing wrong here? I have a data set with date values formatted mm-dd-yyyy.

ex.

[image: Date column sample data]

I am creating a new column with the day extracted from each date, but when I use DAY() function I get #VALUE. I've set the Date column to Date type but to no avail. Any insight would be appreciated.

Edit: Here is the DAY formula im using:

[image]

Comment: What do you get when you do it in this way --> `=DAY(--A2)` seems like they are text formatted, you can use the `Text To Columns` from data tab to convert it as number and then use the `DAY()` function

Comment: Would you show us the formula with the DAY function you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: How to force cell evaluation](https://superuser.com/q/299437/52365)

Comment: @Blackcat I've edited with a screenshot of the formula.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I get the same result when i use =DAY(--E2). I am looking into the Text to Columns - I'm not familiar with that yet so checking it out.

Comment: FevtheDev that worked on my end if its Text Formatted. Also do check the link posted by @GSerg Sir.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya the Text to Columns worked! Why was this step necessary if you don't mind? I had imported the data from a csv file is it that there was some incompatible encoding or something? Thank you!

Comment: @FevtheDev the step was necessary because the date was formatted as Text, in excel numbers are always right aligned while text are always left aligned which is default in nature. unless you have made some text formatting for the alignment, well that said, when its formatted as text, text to columns formats the text dates to true excel dates(Date or times are stored as numbers in excel), and this works with US date formats. I have tried on my end, i face this issue every day lol

Answer (score 2):

As @MayukhBhattacharya suggested above in the comments, the Text to Columns wizard fixed the issue.